# Как правильно задать переменную и далее использовать ее в ссылках вида href (PHP)

Tags: php, переменные, ссылки, href

Есть форма на которой расположены кнопки (ссылки) для скачивания, а также три выпадающих списка: "Отдел", "Месяц", "Год".
Необходимо, при условии выбора определенных значений из выпадающих списков, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку скачивался именно тот файл с сервера, который соответствует выбранным условиям в списках.

Образно говоря, ссылка должна быть вида: `http://ip-adress:port/statistika/dolgi/КОД_ОТДЕЛА/mm/su/КОД_ГОДА/КОД_МЕСЯЦА/file.txt`, где `КОД ОТДЕЛА`,`МЕСЯЦА`,`ГОДА` - коды значений из наших выпадающих списков.

Как правильно создать и описать переменную каждого списка, а затем вставить в свое место в коде ссылки, чтобы при изменении значений переменной скачивался нужный нам файл?

Comment: *готов отблагодарить более материально* - с этим Вам на фриланс, здесь [иная философия](https://stackoverflow.com/company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В событии `onchange` списков сформировать нужный URL и установить его в атрибут `href`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var dep = $("#department").val();
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    if (dep === null || month === null || year === null)
      $("#download").hide();
    else
      $("#download").attr({
        href: 'http://myserver/dep-' + dep +
          '/month-' + month +
          '/year-' + year +
          '/myfile.txt'
      }).show();
  });
  $("#download").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="department">
    <option disabled="disabled">Выберите отдел</option>
    <option value="Код отдела 1">Отдел 1</option>
    <option value="Код отдела 2">Отдел 2</option>
    <option value="Код отдела 3">Отдел 3</option>
</select>

<select id="month">
    <option disabled="disabled">Выберите месяц</option>
    <option value="Код месяца 1">Месяц 1</option>
    <option value="Код месяца 2">Месяц 2</option>
    <option value="Код месяца 3">Месяц 3</option>
</select>

<select id="year">
    <option disabled="disabled">Выберите год</option>
    <option value="Код года 1">Год 1</option>
    <option value="Код года 2">Год 2</option>
    <option value="Код года 3">Год 3</option>
</select>
<p><a id="download" href="">Скачать</a></p>
```

Comment: Я никак не могу понять, почему Ваш скрипт тут работает, а у меня ни в какую не хочет - не формирует ссылку вообще никак. Как-будто ява-скрипт не срабатывает, словно его нет! Причем ни в чистом виде, как он у Вас идет, ни применимо вкупе с моим кодом - никак! ((

Comment: @OlegKasumoff А Вы подключаете библиотеку jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="select.php" method="post">
    <p><select size="2" name="department">
    <option disabled>Выберите отдел</option>
    <option value="Код отдела 1">Отдел 1</option>
    <option selected value="Код отдела 2">Отдел 2</option>
    <option value="Код отдела 3">Отдел 3</option>
   </select></p>

    <p><select size="2" name="month">
    <option disabled>Выберите месяц</option>
    <option value="Код месяца 1">Месяц 1</option>
    <option selected value="Код месяца 2">Месяц 2</option>
    <option value="Код месяца 3">Месяц 3</option>
   </select></p>

    <p><select size="2" name="year">
    <option disabled>Выберите год</option>
    <option value="Код года 1">Год 1</option>
    <option selected value="Код года 2">Год 2</option>
    <option value="Код года 3">Год 3</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

В итоге в PHP вы сможете извлечь из переменной $_POST ваши коды department, month и year, ну а дальше собирайте вашу ссылку. Хотя было бы удобней хранить все ваши файлы в одном каталоге, а в базу записать всю ту же информацию и к ней привязать ссылку на файл